# How to disable hyperref to external documents

Tags: hyperref

Is there an easy way to disable hyperref to tables/figures in external documents.

I would like to keep the table/figure reference in text (e.g., Figure A1), but if I click on it now it sends me back to the top of the page.

Is there any way to disable these hyperrefs solely for an external document, but to keep the text?

I am using \ref and \autoref to refer to the tables/figures 
and 
\externaldocument to load the external document's aux

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how you create cross-references at present. With `\ref`? `\autoref`? `\cref`? Please be specific.

Comment: Thanks Mico, I am using \ref and \autoref. To call the external document I use 
 \externaldocument. I would like to disable links for all the references made in the externaldocument

Comment: To create cross-references without creating a hyperlink, use `\ref*` and `\autoref*`. (This question must have come up before.)

Comment: Is there no way to disable it for all the occurrences in the external document?

Comment: There is perhaps a way, but I won't start to look if you don't provide a sensible example document that can be used for tests.

Comment: In case the external document in question is created using hyperref also: If you use the package [xr-hyper](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper) instead of the package xr, then `\externaldocument` has an optional argument where you can specify the URL, where the external document in question can be found. When the URL is specified, then links to the external document should cause opening the external document and scrolling to the named destination in question.