# Redefining and Conditional Defining of labels

Tags: labels

This is a fairly unimportant itch, but if it is easy/exists, please let me know.  The `\newlabel` macro defines a label and warns if another label wants to overwrite it.  In analogy with `\newcommand` / `\renewcommand` / `\providecommand`,

- Is there a `\providelabel` macro that defines a label only if it has not yet been defined?
- Is there a `\renewlabel` macro that overwrites a label if it exists

This is (marginally) useful when many chapters are in separate tex files and sometimes compiled by themselves, sometimes together with others (into a complete book).  I would like to providelabels from a grepped file from other aux files that fill in only when not already included.

Comment: For the first issue, `\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\providelabel[1]{\ifnum\getrefnumber{#1}=0\relax\label{#1}\fi}`.  For the second, `\label` will overwrite the original label if it exists...of course, it will also generate a warning.

Comment: The `\newlabel` command is only used in `.aux` files. Never in documents.

Comment: Maybe this is of interest to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554052/deactivating-hyperlinks-to-external-documents-with-cleveref
I used it to pull labels from .aux files when separately compiling chapters of lecture notes.